# Обработка нескольких checkbox

Tags: php, yii2

html

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Signup[tag[]]" value="1">name1
<input type="checkbox" name="Signup[tag[]]" value="2">name2
<input type="checkbox" name="Signup[tag[]]" value="3">name3
```

как выловить в php данные синтексис html
Пробовал var_dump[$_POST['Signup]]; выводит только одну позицию

Comment: а дать каждому разные имена и на стороне php проверить каждый отдельно не вариант? либо заранее в js собрать значения в массив в отправить в php одной переменной. и var_dump`у вместо квадратных скобок нужны обычные

Comment: То есть с таким синтаксисом не возможно получить массив выбранных чекбоксов?